# Replace all backslashes in a string with a pipe

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the string: \rnosapmdwq\salesforce\R3Q\OutputFiles\Archive

I'm getting a unrecognized escape sequence when I try to send this to a .NET web service.

I'm trying to replace all of the "\" with "|" to send it to the server.

I know I can use the **replace** method but that only replaces the first element.  I think I need to use a regular expression to solve it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Path = Path.replace("\\/g", "|");
```

This is wrong though.

Comment: are backslashes in the original string escaped, i.e. `"\\rnosapmdwq\\sales..."`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You don't need to make a regex a string, and it helps having that first `/` in there

```
Path = Path.replace(/\\/g, "|")
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax would be: `Path  = Path.replace(/\\/g, "|");`

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/eDKej/.

Example (extra code for demonstration purposes only):

```
var Path = $("#path").text();
Path  = Path.replace(/\\/g, "|");
$("#new-path").append(Path);
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually noticed that after I posted my solution. I'm so used to having to replace forward slashes when submitting paths into a database.